# What kind of words are "given", "considering" vs "even though" and "because"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, conjunctions

I am curious about the words "considering", "given", and "even though", because they seem to help me build sentences, but I don't know how they work.

Some example sentences:

> She can speak English quite well, **considering that** she only started learning it one year ago.
>
> She can speak English quite well, **even though** she only started learning it one year ago.
>
> I'll let you rewrite the test, **given** your special circumstances.

I know that conjunctions like "because" can be used to build sentences in a similar way:

> I'll let you rewrite the test, **because of** your special circumstances.

Wikitionary says that [considering](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/considering) and [given](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/given) are prepositions. But I know "because" is a conjunction, and wiktionary says that [even though](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/even_though) is also a conjunction (and not a preposition).

Questions:
1. What is the difference between how prepositions ("considering", "given") are building these sentences, versus the conjunctions ("because", "even though")?
2. Can many other verbs (other than "to consider" and "to give") be made into prepositions?

Answer (score 1):

Those words are [subordinating conjunctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)#Subordinating_conjunctions). They can become prepositions when followed by an object rather than a dependent clause.

Comment: Note the highlighted word in this line from the link that you provided "**Some** subordinating conjunctions, when used to introduce a phrase instead of a full clause, become prepositions with identical meanings." I can't think of any examples with **because**. Could you please edit your question to add an example? Note that **because of** is a preposition.

Answer (score 0):

> I'll let you rewrite the test, **because** you were sick when you took it the first time. -*conjunction*
> I'll let you rewrite the test, **because of** your special circumstances. - *preposition*

**because** is a conjunction, and must be followed by a clause- something that contains a verb. **[because of](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/because-of)** is a preposition, and must be followed by a noun, pronoun, noun phrase or noun clause. In your example, it is followed by a noun phrase "your special circumstances".

You can analyse sentences with **considering** and **given** in more than one way. You could say that they are both prepositions, or you could say that **considering** is a present participle and **given** is an past participle. If you go for the participle analysis, the participle and what follows is a participle clause, which plays an adverbial role in the sentence. If you go for the preposition analysis, it's a preposition phrase, which also plays an adverbial role in the sentence.

Yes, you can use other verbs to form participle clauses:

> I'll let you rewrite the test, **knowing** your special circumstances
> I'll let you rewrite the test, **taking into account** your special circumstances

---

Note that "rewrite a test" is American English. British speakers would say "retake" or "resit".